# Remove Install Receiver or remove Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, install-referrer

I need to **remove Firebase-Analytics** from our Android app because their install referrer receiver prevents my Third party application to track installs. Only one is allowed.

Did anyone ever faced that issue? 
How would you do?

I tried this, but this the broadcastreceiver/install receiver is present

```
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-analytics'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove receiver by using Manifest merger rules

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" tools:node="remove"/>
```

But I'm not sure that Firebase appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the gradle

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
}
```